# Membership design with multiple portals

Tags: database-design

We have decided to build a custom membership database that will serve 2 portals with similair functionallity.

Option 1)
Use 1 membership database, that serves both portals with some kind of functionallity that distingusich a user from portal 1 and 2.

Option 2)
Membership 1 and membership 2 database, that serves each portal.

What would be a good strategy?

Comment: It would probably be appropriate to use one database and using a roles system, grant access to the appropriate portal. ie: `ROLE_USER_PORTAL_A`, `ROLE_USER_PORTAL_B`. This would allow centralized user management, single-sign-on (potentially), one password, and access to as many or few portals with as many appropriate roles as necessary.

Comment: Roles might be interesting in this context. Yes we will have SSO per portal, as it will host a number of applications per portal, but besides that there will be no interaction between portal 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good strategy will be have separate databases for each portal, but use single LDAP or OAuth server as auth data source.